# Using Euler's relation to transform to cosine

Tags: signal-processing, euler-mascheroni-constant, eulers-method

[image]

input is $f_2(t) = Acos(w_0 t + \phi)$

output $y_2(t)$ is $\frac{A}{2} e^{j \phi} H(jw_0) e^{jw_0 t} + \frac{A}{2} e^{-j \phi} H(-jw_0) e^{jw_0 t} $

okay so I need the step in between, how were the terms in the Re{} achieved?

Like, what happened to the negatives? $e^{-j \phi}, H(-jw_0)$ and so on?

It's almost like $e^{2t} + e^{-2t} = \frac{e^{4x} + 1}{e^{2t}}$

yet the answer doesn't look like that at all

I'm confused

Also, it's related to Linear Time Invariant systems, and the terms are supposed to be "conjugate pairs".

Comment: You do have a couple of hundred reputation so it should not really be news: Please try and typeset the mathematics you put in questions.

Comment: @mathreadler given that everything is very readable, I don't see the issue.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I've seen it said by so many high rep users by now so I was rather sure it was a rule. Haven't checked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, denote
$$
z = Ae^{j\phi}H(j \omega_0)e^{j \omega_0t}
$$
First, note that $y_2(t)$ can be rewritten as $\frac 12 (z + \overline{z})$, which is simply $\operatorname{Re}\{z\}$.  In particular: note that for any real number $x$, we have $\overline{e^{jx}} = e^{-jx}$. Moreover, we can rewrite
$$
z = Ae^{j \phi}[H(j \omega_0)]e^{j \omega_0t} = A \left[|H(j\omega_0)| e^{j\angle H(j \omega_0)}\right] e^{j \phi} e^{j \omega_0 t} = 
A |H(j\omega_0)| e^{j[\angle H(j \omega_0) +  \phi +  \omega_0 t]}
$$
So, we have
$$
y_2(t) = \operatorname{Re}\{z\} = 
\operatorname{Re}\left\{
\left[A |H(j\omega_0)|\right] e^{j[\angle H(j \omega_0) +  \phi +  \omega_0 t]}
\right\} =\\
A |H(j\omega_0)|
\operatorname{Re}\left\{
e^{j[\angle H(j \omega_0) +  \phi +  \omega_0 t]}
\right\} = \\
A |H(j\omega_0)| \cos \left[\angle H(j \omega_0) +  \phi +  \omega_0 t \right]
$$
as desired.

Comment: is it called superposition principle? What is it called? How do you know it can be written as Re{z} Also what is z?

Comment: Write out $z = a + bi$.  What do you get when you compute $\frac{z + \bar z}{2}$?  Try it out.

Comment: what is a, what is b? I know i is imaginary Why do you not have negative $e^{-jw_0t}$

Comment: Sorry.  I mean that if $z = a + jb$ (for real numbers $a,b$), then we have
$$
\frac{z + \bar z}{2} = \frac{[a + jb] + [a - jb]}{2} = \frac{2a}{2} = a = \operatorname{Re}\{z\}
$$

Comment: No, I have never heard this referred to as "the superposition principle".  In fact, I have heard of no name for this formula.

Comment: why is your z different from my $y_2(t)$?? I thought $ f_2(t)$ transforms to what I wrote. You don't have Euler constant with negative power, why?

Comment: Do you understand the first three words of my answer?

Comment: oooh so you just assigned to variable z the positive term to make a point with its conjugate pair, huh? Why couldn't you say so!

Comment: Well, I tried to say so.  Obviously the phrasing which would be clearest to me is not the phrasing that is clearest to you (I would object that I have not idea what "the positive term" is supposed to mean.  And why are we assigning things to variables?  This isn't computer programming).  In any case: now that we're on the same page, does everything make sense?

Comment: the positive term(s) are $\frac{A}{2} e^{j \phi} H(jw_0) e^{jw_0 t} + $ in the $y_2(t)$ euler transform(?) And yeah, it does makes sense! I guess I'm supposed to say "thanks" now...

Comment: @Jack well, they're not positive: $e^{j \phi}$ and $e^{j \omega_0 t}$ are complex numbers.  Note also that my $z$ doesn't have the $\frac 12$.

Comment: @Jack "You're welcome".  By the way: the fact that the second term is $\overline{z}$ (where $z$, as we established, is the "positive term") is what they (the textbook? teacher? notes?) meant when they said that the terms are "conjugate pairs".

Comment: uh no it's just what I came up with...

Comment: wait a sec, hold up, wouldn't $e^{2t}$ and $e^{-2t}$ be conjugate pairs?? Therefore the same method should apply, no?  $e^{2t} + e^{-2t} = e^{2t} $???? Or that rule only applies to eulers with complex terms?

Comment: @Jack only applies for things like $e^{-j2t}$, where the exponent is purely imaginary.

Comment: hey you seem to be knowledgeable, do you know this http://i.imgur.com/ID61BIR.png exponential fourier transform of a sketched periodic signal, in particular, why are the boundaries between $- \frac{pi}{4} and \frac{pi}{4}$ ??? Like, $T_0$ is pi, right? (period). Difference between  $- \frac{pi}{4} and \frac{pi}{4}$  isn't pi, it's pi/2. I also don't get where that 4t comes from I mean I know x(t) formula is kinda like $\frac{wnt}{T_0}$; w = 2, so why is it 4 in the numerator? p.s. don't think it's worth another thread

Comment: @Jack you're not taking the flat part of the signal into account. The correct formula for $x(t)$ over $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ is given by
$$
x(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & -\pi/2 \leq x < -\pi/4\\
\frac{4t}{\pi} & -\pi/4 \leq x \leq \pi/4\\
0 & \pi/4 < x \leq \pi/2
\end{cases}
$$
Check that putting a $4$ in the numerator gives us the right slope for that line. Now, plug into your formula with $T_0 = \pi$, as you said.

Comment: wait, why do you use pi/2 as a boundary? are you supposed to use arbitrary interval? And why is it 4t/pi?

Comment: @Jack any interval of length $\pi$ works just as well.  We could have also used $[0,\pi]$, for example.  And again: *check the slope* of the line, using the graph.